# - the bounded metric on $R$ by $\bar{d}=\frac{|x-y|}{1+|x-y|}$ Define a subset which is closed and bounded but not compact. (Explain why not compact)

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, general-topology, analysis

- the bounded metric on $R$ by $\bar{d}=\frac{|x-y|}{1+|x-y|}$ Define a subset which is closed and bounded but not compact. (Explain why not compact)

$\mathbb N$ is a closed and bounded set for this metric which is not compact. Open sets for this metric are same as those for the usual metric so closedness and compactness are same for the two metrics.

For showing that the two metrics has the same closed sets (hence same open/compact sets) just show that $d(x_n,x) \to 0$ iff $|x_n-x| \to 0$ (Thanks for helping to @KaviRamaMurthy)

To show this: Let $\varepsilon>0 .$ Assume there is a $N$ in $\mathbb{N}$ such that for all $n \geq N,\left|x_{n}-x\right| \rightarrow 0 .$ So clearly we get
$d\left(x_{n}, x\right)=\frac{\left|x_{n}-x\right|}{1+\left|x_{n}-x\right|} \rightarrow 0$

**Can you check, How can I show other direction?**

Comment: The equivalence of metrics follows from continuity of $f(x)=\frac{x}{1+x}$ at $x=0$, essentially, as a map from $[0,\infty)$ to itself.

Comment: You haven't shown the first direction. You start off as if you were using the definition of convergence, with the $\epsilon$ and $N$. But then you forget what the rest of that definition says and basically say it's true because clearly it's true. That demonstrates nothing. Go back and read the defintion of convergence. Note where you left it, and follow through. You are only allowed to say "clearly", "obviously" or the like if you actually know how to produce that proof,

Comment: $\mathbb R$ itself is bounded and closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have $\overline d(x,y) \le \lvert x  - y \rvert$ because $1 + \lvert x  - y \rvert \ge 1$. This shows that $\lvert x_n  - x \rvert \to 0$ implies $\overline d(x_n,x) \to 0$.

If $\overline d(x_n,x) \to 0$, then each $\epsilon > 0$ admits $N$ such that $\overline d(x_n,x) < \epsilon' = \frac{1}{2}\min(\epsilon,1)$ for $n \ge N$. But then $\lvert x_n  - x \rvert < \frac{\epsilon'}{1 - \epsilon'} \le 2\epsilon' \le \epsilon$.

Comment: Thanks for answer